# Tracing int 0x80 instructions using PIN

Tags: instrumentation

I wrote this small pintool that tries to record the number of `int 0x80` instructions executed. I did this roughly as follows :-

`xed_iclass_enum_t iclass = static_cast<xed_iclass_enum_t>(INS_Opcode(ins));`

I then compare iclass against XED_ICLASS_INT and print out the EIP if found. I'm doing this on a statically compiled test binary that :-

```
1. Prints hello world
2. Makes a call to mprotect
```

However, the number of `int 0x80` instructions encountered is just one. Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong? I tried using XED_ICLASS_SYSCALL too but that did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## PIN_AddSyscallEntryFunction

Why not just use `PIN_AddSyscallEntryFunction`?  This is an ABI-agnostic way of doing things, that lets you use `PIN_GetSyscallArgument` and related functions rather than manually inspecting the stack and register context.

## INS_IsInterrupt

You could also use `INS_IsInterrupt` at instrumentation time to gather the information at analysis time.  Note that this won't catch any systemm calls made via the `syscall` or `sysenter` instructions.

## Examples

As a simple example, if you look at the file [`inscount0.cpp`](https://github.com/JonathanSalwan/stuffz/blob/master/binary_analysis_with_ins_counts/inscount0.cpp#L48) that comes with Pin, if you add the following check, you'll only instrument syscalls.

#### INS_IsInterrupt

In `inscount0.cpp`, change the routines as shown below.  The module will now count the number of `int` instructions executed, rather than the total number of instructions executed.

```
VOID Instruction(INS ins, VOID *v)
{
    if(INS_IsSyscall(ins))
    {
        INS_InsertCall(ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)docount, IARG_END);
    }
}
```

Now all syscall instructions will be counted.  You can use the standard `INS_InsertCall` arguments to inspect the stack or register context.

#### PIN_AddSyscallEntryFunction

Add this function before `main`

```
void OnSyscall(THREADID threadIndex, CONTEXT *ctxt, SYSCALL_STANDARD std, VOID *v)
{
    printf("Made syscall #%i\n", PIN_GetSyscallNumber(ctxt, std));
}
```

and add this line to `main` before `PIN_StartProgram`.

```
PIN_AddSyscallEntryFunction(OnSyscall, 0);
```